# Dynamically Change Pop-Up Content from External Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have a counter that counts the number of viewers in a chat room and gets displayed on my main website above the chat. This is pulled via json from a script running in my main website. If the user wants to pop out the chat they should be able to click a button and it should pop up. The problem comes when I need to grab the viewers value from my main websites script and placing it in a div dynamically inside the pop up, without refreshing it.

I was trying to avoid calling the json twice because on my main website it's already being called every second. I tried to create a simple test to see dynamically change the text color of the popup from an external javascript file (that's not linked in the pop up).

My external javascript file has a function that's being called when the user clicks a link:

```
function popUp() {
    newwindow=window.open('mod.html','test','height=200,width=150');
        newwindow.focus();
    $('#blue').css('color', 'red');
    return false;
}
```

This is the contents of my mod.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <div id="blue" style="color:blue">
        This is Blue
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not getting an error but I'm also not getting any results...

**TL;DR** *How do I change text in a pop up from an external javascript file not linked in the pop up.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that your pop-up is a completely separate browser window and thus needs to do everything itself, and thus you must do the ajax call in this page's DOM too.

The long answer is you're probably better with a "popup" div styled nicely with CSS that includes the specified content rather than opening a whole new browser window.  See http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/  If you've got a div popup, it's just another div, and you can highlight, alter content, etc just like any other div on the page.

Comment: and that's much better looking than a normal pop-up window. I'll have to check that out thanks :3   I'll come back and checkmark it if it works out.

Comment: Ok, so the only problem I found with this is (1) I'd have to include another framework (UI) which is pretty killer and it's kinda big. (2) There's no real way to minimize it since it is not a real'window', just a div. I did see some examples of modding it to make it minimize but it just seemed all a bit much for 1 module window. I'm thinking for efficiency it might be best to just do another ajax call via the pop-up unless there's a better alternative.